# Maven Versions Description

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I was making some changes to the POM of my project and noticed that they had some new versions of the MySQL connector, but I could not understand what the abbreviations meant after each version.

As in the example below, `rc` and `dmr` what do they mean? Do you have a link to the documentation for these abbreviations?

[image]

Comment: Probably this: RC = Release Candidate, DMR = Developer Milestone Release. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-versions.html). Note that the RC and DMR are both pre-release versions which should not be used for production.